# Error in $A.getCallback() [ReferenceError: $ is not defined]

Tags: jquery

This is my controller code :

```
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getpickval");
    var inputsel = component.find("InputSelectDynamic");

    var opts=[];
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){
            opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
        }
        inputsel.set("v.options", opts);
        console.log($("#optionValue")[0]);
         $("#optionValue").hide();   
         $(".number").show();

    });

     //document.getElementById("optionValue").style.visibility = "hidden";

    $A.enqueueAction(action);       

},
```

Here I want to hide  optionValue div and show div with class named as number on my init handler. Now above error is resolved but still these hide and show functions of jquery are not working. I am using jquery 2.2.4

Comment: What is the name of your static resource?

Comment: @ Mohith jquery224

Answer (score 1):

In addition Mohith's comment you may have a conflict with using the $ variable in Salesforce Lightning.  You may want to use [**jQuery's noConflict function**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to remap the $ variable to something like $j.  I know that noConflict re-mapping is usually needed on VisualForce pages which incorporate jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The correct tag will be

```
<ltng:require styles="/resource/slds090/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" scripts="/resource/jquery224" />
```

You do not need any timestamp there .

Comment: Also it looks like the OP is trying to use `$` inside the init handler,there might be timing issue too, which i thinks is the main problem.So it's better to use the `afterScriptLoaded` while trying to use `$` or any 3rd part libraries.

Comment: You might be correct .Hope the author of question posts some code .But the way jquery was referenced is also wrong .

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava  Thanks.. Now error has been resolved but jquery functions .hide() , .show() are still not working.

Comment: Please post full code so we help better

Comment: I have posted full code @Mohit

Comment: @Raseeka how are you loading jquery script in your component?

Comment: @ Mohit I am loading jquery as: <ltng:require styles="/resource/slds090/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css" scripts="/resource/jquery224" />